# UI layout framework library

Tags: library, c++, c#, gui, c

Is there a library (preferably C#, C, C++) that specifically deals with container layouts and resizing the components?

As in, it would provide an object that will automatically resize and layout components, but it leaves it up to the developer to add in the components they want?

For example, I do not want Qt or friends because it does both the layout *and* the rendering. I have a custom renderer and I want the ability to say "I want a box that is 640x480, and then inside it I want a component that spans the left side with a max width of 300 (but shrinks if its content is smaller) and then a right component that fills the rest of the space" while leaving it up to me to provide info on the internals. I'd have to provide callback functions that return the desired dimensions and such since the components, at some point, have to query something for dimensions.

Basically I just want a library that acts as the layout specifier, and gives me back a bunch of bounding boxes which I can then use elsewhere.